# A question about a special Geometric sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $z$ be an element on unit circle in complex plane. Then we have series $\Sigma_{i=0}^{i=+\infty} z^{i}$. when does this series convergent?

$\Sigma _{i=0}^{+\infty} z^{i}=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-z^{n}}{1-z}$. I don't know how to move on from this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series will not be convergent as $\mid z^n \mid = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and therefore $\mid z^n \mid$ doesnot converge to zero which is a necessary condition for convergent of a series.

Comment: So this series doesn’t convergent anywhere.

Comment: Not on unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = e^{i2\pi\theta}$
and suppose $\theta \in [0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. 
Thus let say $\theta = p/q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p < q$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q \ne 0$.
Then 
$$ z^q = e^{i2\pi\theta q} = e^{i2\pi p} = 1 $$
Therefore, for any $n$, 
\begin{equation}
z^n = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n \equiv 0$ mod $q$} \\
e^{i2\pi r} &  \text{if $n \equiv r$ mod $q$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Thus 
$\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$ could possibly have at most $q$ values depends on $\theta$ and $n$.
Therefore, the limit does not exist.
Then $\theta$ is irrational, one can show that $\{z^n| n \in \mathbb{N}\} =$ Unit circle.